# How to get Born effective charge using ph.x for compounds whose constituents are metallic?

Tags: quantum-espresso, phonons

In the examples directory of Quantum ESPRESSO PHonon package, [example15](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/tree/develop/PHonon/examples/example15) shows how to get Raman and Infrared spectra. In the example it contains two compounds ZnO and CO2. In case of CO2, in the `ph.x` input file, we can put `epsil = .true.`. However, in case of ZnO, which have metallic constituent, we have to do the calculation with `epsil = .false.`. Hence it cannot create Born effective charge file and also therefore no LO-TO splitting in phonon optical modes. The output file give the message following:

`Z* not found in file MnScFeGa222.fc, TO-LO splitting at q=0 will be absent!`

It generates the phonon dispersion curve without any LO-TO spiting at gamma. So my question is: is the LO-TO spiting zero for all metallic compounds? Quantum ESPRESSO always give zero LO-TO splitting unless `epsil = .true.`. But we cannot set it `.true.` for metallic systems.  Hence we cannot create Born effective charge file. Can please anyone share your valuable knowledge on that?

Comment: Welcome to our community! This question was flagged as "very low quality". Please make a serious effort to fix the grammar, formatting, and pay serious attention to it. For example you have started your last sentence with a lower-case letter, and you have added a period after a question mark, and you have no stylized Quantum ESPRESSO correctly and you've started words like "phono" with a capital letter rather even though it wasn't the first word of a sentence nor was it used as a "proper noun". **Please take these suggestions seriously since questions in the VLQ review queue can get deleted**.

Comment: *Some optical calculations in Quantum ESPRESSO work only for semiconductors or insulators. This is because the metallic system has an infinite dielectric constant at ω=0, which is required in some calculations.* - [Nguyen Tuan Hung, Ahmad R.T. Nugraha, Riichiro Saito. Quantum ESPRESSO Course for Solid-State Physics. Page: 113-125](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/chapters/mono/10.1201/9781003290964-1/introduction-tuan-hung-nguyen-ahmad-nugraha-riichiro-saito)

Comment: is it possible to have born effective charges and hence LO-TO spiting  for compound consist of both metal and non metal elements

Comment: I think you should be able to set `epsil = .true.` even if there are metal atoms/ions, as long as the *system* has a valence energy gap. LiF has a dielectric constant, while Li metal does not. I'm pretty sure ZnO is an insulator, so you should be able to have your dielectric constant and Born effective charges with no problem.